# NSStringFromClass can return nil when the arg isn't nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm getting some weird behavior in my CoreData wrapper class. Here's the function:

```
-(SystemCode*) getSystemCodeWithDescription:(NSString*)description andType:(Class)type {
    NSString* entityName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", type]; 
    // NSStringFromClass(type); was my first try, it also returned a nil string
    SystemCode* result = [self getUniqueEntity:entityName predicate:@"Description == '%@'" predicateArg:description generateNew:NO];
    return result;
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on the 2nd line (SystemCode* result = ...) and run GDB I get the following output:

```
(gdb) print-object entityName
Unable to access variable "entityName"
Can't print the description of a NIL object.
(gdb) print-object type
Result
```

How can 'type' be a valid object, but when I try to convert it to a string, it just turns in to a nil string? My project is using the XCode 4.0 and running in the iPad 4.3 simulator if that matters.

Comment: For clarification: the class that the object 'type' is referencing is called Result, which inherits from SystemCode.

Comment: And `SystemCode` eventually inherits from `NSObject`, correct?

Comment: Yah, SystemCode inherits from NSManagedObject

Comment: It looks like your problem is that `stringWithFormat:` is returning nil. Does providing something else as the second argument (e.g. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"TEST"]`) work?

Comment: Chuck: yup, stringWithFormat still functions properly

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `type` is a `Class`?

Also, you can use `po` instead of `print-object`.

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately, yes type is a Class. I ran some test code 
 SystemCode* test = [type alloc];
 NSLog(@"test type: %@", [test class]);
and that prints out 'test type: Result'

Comment: OK -- that is truly bizarre. Try `NSLog(@"%p %@", type, type);`.  Hrm-- if this is an entity's class, it might be dynamically defined and that may trip up NSStringFromClass(), but I can't imagine that to be true.

Comment: That log spits out: "0x5a2a8, Result", but NSStringFromClass, of course, still returns nil.

Comment: Can you check regions in the VM instrument?  See if 0x5a2a8 is in a malloc region or in mapped memory?   I suspect it is a dynamically generated class, but NSStringFromClass() shouldn't trip over that.

Comment: Um, I've never used that instrument before. Also, I'm not familiar with the differences between dynamic and normal classes. Is a dynamic class one build entirely at runtime with reflection? Because this class is defined by me, but it has a bunch of @dynamic properties that are defined by CoreData.

Comment: Do you have an `@interface` for that class?  I.e. it isn't dynamically defined by Core Data as a part of your model?  OK -- then something else even more strange is going on (Yes, a dynamic class would be built entirely at runtime, which Core Data can do).  File a bug and attach your binary.  This is weird.  If you can minimize teh test case, all the better.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. The class was working correctly, someone checked in a build target for debug that was optimized. It was just that gdb couldn't see the values. My bug was actually in the predicate, that's why no entities were being selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `class_getName` from `<objc/runtime.h>`.

Comment: That won't help;  `NSStringFromClass()` is just a wrapper around that function.